# Where are the properties of GUI elements stored while using GUIDE (MATLAB GUI)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

The properties can only be edited through the MATLAB property toolbox. It doesn't show up on the m-file. It shows only the create and callback functions. No property assignments can be seen. Where are the properties being stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a GUI that you created in GUIDE, it saves both a `.m` file and a `.fig` file.

The `.fig` file is actually a `.mat` file, it just has a different extension. If you rename it and load it in, you'll find that the `.mat` file contains variables that are handles to the GUI figure and all its components. All the properties are there, just like they would be if you'd just created them.

(You'll also find that the GUI components have some extra information stored in them, either in their `UserData` property or in their application data - see `doc getappdata` to find out about this - that stores additional information about the GUI structure, such as the name of the `.m`-file associated with the GUI `.fig`-file).